# Error while selecting rows from datatable where criteria is datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I want to select some records from table where criteria is datetime and the query looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.vw_A3_MO_Header_OPF WHERE [Data Creazione] > '2014-01-27';
```

When I run this query from my application than I get error:

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in
>   an out-of-range datetime

in data table filed Data Creazione shows values like:

```
2014-01-27 12:34:00
```

If I use same query from MSSQL it works. Why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Use `convert` :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM dbo.vw_A3_MO_Header_OPF 
WHERE [Data Creazione] > convert(datetime,'2014-01-27',121)
```